# Pulling Historical Stock Data

Tags: php

Let me start off by saying thank you so much to the stacked overflow community dont know how I would get anything done with out you guys but enough brown noosing.

But today im having a issue that im hopeing someone can help with I am using these two scripts to pull data from fiance.yahoo but im not capable of acheving what I need through these.

```
 <?php
 include_once('pulldata.php');

 $objYahooStock = new YahooStock;

 /**
Add format/parameters to be fetched

s = Symbol
n = Name
l1 = Last Trade (Price Only)
d1 = Last Trade Date
t1 = Last Trade Time
c = Change and Percent Change
v = Volume
  */
 $objYahooStock->addFormat("snl1d1t1cv");

 /**
     Add company stock code to be fetched

msft = Microsoft
amzn = Amazon
yhoo = Yahoo
goog = Google
aapl = Apple   
  */
 $objYahooStock->addStock("msft");
 $objYahooStock->addStock("amzn");
 $objYahooStock->addStock("yhoo");     
 $objYahooStock->addStock("goog");
 $objYahooStock->addStock("vgz");

 /**
  * Printing out the data
  */
 foreach( $objYahooStock->getQuotes() as $code => $stock)
 {
?>
Code: <?php echo $stock[0]; ?> <br />
Name: <?php echo $stock[1]; ?> <br />
Last Trade Price: <?php echo $stock[2]; ?> <br />
Last Trade Date: <?php echo $stock[3]; ?> <br />
Last Trade Time: <?php echo $stock[4]; ?> <br />
Change and Percent Change: <?php echo $stock[5]; ?> <br />
Volume: <?php echo $stock[6]; ?> <br /><br />
<?php
 }
 ?>
```

along with this little snippet to pull the data from yahoo

```
<?php
class YahooStock {
 private $stocks = array();
 private $format;
 public function addStock($stock)
{
    $this->stocks[] = $stock;
}
 public function addFormat($format)
{
    $this->format = $format;
}
 public function getQuotes()
{       
    $result = array();     
    $format = $this->format;

    foreach ($this->stocks as $stock)
    {           
       $s = file_get_contents("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$stock&f=$format&e=.csv");
             $data = explode( ',', $s);
             $result[$stock] = $data;
    }
    return $result;
}
}
```

But this isnt capable of what I want to do specificy. I am looking to have it pull historical data and not just by the day something like how this looks
         http://investing.money.msn.com/investments/charts/?symbol=fslr#{"zRange":"1","startDate":"2013-7-25","endDate":"2013-7-25","chartStyle":"mountain","chartCursor":"1","scaleType":"0","yaxisAlign":"right","mode":"pan"}

If you visit that website it will display all the data for the stock FSLR for the day in 5 minute increments. Im not sure how to scrape this data from this website and or get data much like it from yahoo finance Ive already even tried looking through the html to see if its stored there. but came up with nothing any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out a new network to get everything from google finance gives the data and its easily exported.

Thanks